# Make git repo from a clone and preserve the history

Tags: git

Need to migrate a git repository from gitserver G1 to git server G2. Issue is that both G1 and G2 are in their respective private networks and cannot access each other directly. 
I have access to both the servers from my machine. What I am trying to do is clone the repository from G1 to my local machine copy and scp that cloned project to G2. Now, Could you please let me know:

1. How to turn this clone on G2 into a proper repository, so that others can clone it afterwards.
2. Is there a better way to do it.

We normally create a clone from git repo, here I need to do the opposite, i.e. how do we create a git repo from a clone so that the history is preserved.

Thanks,

Kapil

Answer (score 2):

Create a blank repo on server G2. Then on the local repo, run:

```
git remote add G2 <blank_repo_url>
git push —all G2
```

Because Git is designed to be decentralised, history is maintained when you push to a new repository.

Comment: by G2 in the above commands it means origin or the IP of the server ?Sorry for the stupid Question, I am bit naive

Comment: I am getting something like this:git push --all origin
ssh: connect to host 10.50.1.50 port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: my ssh connection is working properly, i can ssh to that machine.

Comment: Edmund Thanks for the help. The issue was with the network. I could get the repository pushed to the remote server.